# Variables in separate class coming back null

Tags: objective-c, macos, class, variables

Ok, I think the question I had here was long-winded and difficult to get through. I'll simplify my question:

- I have a class called **InController**.
- **InController** has a method called `nextPage` that tells an int variable, `inPageNumber`, to add one onto itself and to call on another **InController** method called `updateTable`.
- `updateTable` clears a table, **inTable**, of its current data and fills it with data relevant to the page number it retrieves from `inPageNumber`.
- The table, **inTable**, is contained inside an `NSBox` with specific printing requirements.
- I subclassed `NSBox` into a class called **CustomViewPagination** to meet these printing requirements, overriding its paginations methods. Basically, when a new printing page is required, it attempts to print the same area again, but calls on `nextPage` to fill the table with the data of the sequential page.

With me so far?

One of the pagination methods I overrided in **CustomViewPagination**, `beginPageInRect`, is automatically called for each printed page by default. Because of this, I placed a call to my **InController** method of `nextPage`, to change the **inTable** data for the current printing page.

My problem is when I call `nextPage` (which is a method in **InController**) from my **CustomViewPagination** class. It does nothing and when I debug it I find that all the variables required in the method are nil. However, they are the correct values when I call `nextPage` from inside **InController**.

---

## File Extracts:

**InController.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "CustomViewPagination.h"

@interface InController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *inPreview;
    IBOutlet CustomViewPagination *inSheet;
    NSArray *iSelectedIn;
    NSMutableArray *records;
    int inPageNumber;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *iSelectedIn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *records;
```

**InController.m:**

```
#import "InController.h"

@implementation InController

@synthesize iSelectedIn, records;

- (IBAction) inNextPage:(id)sender {
    inPageNumber = inPageNumber + 1;
    NSLog(@"inPageNumber called ok");
    [self updateIn];
}


- (IBAction)updateInvoice:(id)sender {
    //wipe all current records and refresh empty table
    [records removeAllObjects];
    [inPreviewTable reloadData];
    for (NSArray *s in [[iSelectedIn valueForKey:@"inJobList"] lastObject]) {
        NSString *jLT = [s valueForKey:@"inJT"];
        NSString *jLH = [s valueForKey:@"inJHo"];
        NSString *jLC = [s valueForKey:@"inJC"];
        // etc.
        // if CustomViewPagination called this, records is nil, so nothing
        // is cleared, and there's no *s for iSelectedIn as iSelectedIn
        // is found to be nil. If InController called this, it works fine.
```

**CustomViewPagination.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class InController;

@interface CustomViewPagination : NSBox {
    InController *inControllerInstance;
}

@end
```

**CustomViewPagination.m:**

```
#import "CustomViewPagination.h"
#import "InController.h"

@implementation CustomViewPagination

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    inControllerInstance = [[InController alloc] init];
}

- (void)beginPageInRect:(NSRect)aRect atPlacement:(NSPoint)location {
    int pageCounter = [[NSPrintOperation currentOperation] currentPage];
    if (pageCounter == 1) {
        // Don't respond to 1st page, do nothing.
    } else {
        [inControllerInstance inNextPage:self];
    }
    [super beginPageInRect:aRect atPlacement:location];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where is your burbController init method? (Note Class names always start Uppercase - BurbController. Also you have an errant semi-colon at the end of your -beginPageInRect method )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 2 IBOutlets in `InController` (`inPreview` & `inSheet`), but `InController` is created programmatically in `CustomViewPagination's` `awakeFromNib`.

How are the Outlets connected? (Can't be from within IB, as you are creating the `InController` instance programmatically). This would be an explanation why both are `nil`.

Comment: Ok, this avenue of investigation is different than anything I've read/been offered so far. I'm intrigued. I get the basics of what you're saying but I'm a little thrown. I've connected the **CustomViewPagination** `inSheet` to the single CVP object in my interface that uses the overrided subclass methods. The reason for this is that I later identify it by name when I describe what to print in an `NSPrintOperation`. How would I avoid using outlets to do this? Or else avoid creating it programmatically in awakeFromNib and only use the outlets (basically, use one or the other).

Comment: inSheet is an outlet of InController. To connect an outlet with an object, you need to instantiate that object in IB.  If you did that and you are creating another InController instance in CustomViewPagination's awakeFromNib:, you end up with 2 distinct InController instances. One that is connected within the nib and one that receives the messages you send from beginPageInRect:. To me it sounds you just want to have one InController around. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct :) I'm up to speed on what you're saying at the start. I realise now I'm using two habits that shouldn't cross over. I took some initiative there and removed my init of **InController** in **CustomViewPagination's** `awakeFromNib` and instead connected an outlet to the InController in my Nib palette. Now I'm unsure how to address the same instance InController, like you were suggesting I would want to do (and I do).

Comment: You made inControllerInstance an IBOutlet right?  So you can send inNextPage to inControllerInstance. Just set a breakpoint in beginPageInRect and check if inControllerInstance is not nil. I don't know enough about your design. But you might consider refactoring some parts (Maybe using an NSViewController) to avoid passing controller instances into view classes.

Comment: I'm moreso having trouble making an IBOutlet to an *instance* of **inController**. I can outlet to the class in the nib palette fine but obviously I get warnings saying the class may not respond to my method calls as they're not class level. What is the most straightforward way of using IBOutlet to pass on an instance of **InController**. Usually at this stage I alloc and init the class but this is what's creating a separate instance and causing me the grief.

Comment: Where do you create your InController? Do you have an instance of it in IB (I assumed that you have) or do you create it elsewhere? The "not class level warnings" are related to this? Please update your original post with the warnings and your current code.

Comment: Beautiful! I've finally got it to work after days of banging my head against the wall. The 50 reputation is yours. Thanks! I did have an instance in IB but I was still managing to call the class of it rather than the instance from my outlet. When I tried to make it reference the instance I was getting errors and these had been throwing me off before. It turns out I had to put a forward class of InController in my header also and it's all working like I hoped.

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe you can clean up your code to avoid the forward declaration (& the controller in your view class: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) ;)